# Maintain existing In-App-Purchase Product Availability after Developer Transfer (Mac and iOS)

Tags: ios, macos, app-store

I have purchased a small developer that has a Mac app and an iOS app. The apps on both platforms use in-app purchase (non-subscription). I want these apps to continue to allow their in app purchases once they are transferred to me. I don't want to create a new build for either platform at this time.

The iOS Developer Library document about transferring and deleting apps is vague on this topic; and I couldn't find a relevant section in the Mac documentation at all. The iOS documentation infers the products are created automatically, but I would appreciate anyone with experience providing an explicit answer.

Will the existing in-app purchases continue to be valid and available for sale once I transfer the apps over to my ownership within iTunes Connect?

Does this work the same way for both Mac and iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the existing in-app purchases continue to be valid and available for sale once the app is transferred over.

The app keeps the same identifier (com.company.appid) even though it's now associated with your company and the app also keeps all of the same product ids or In-App Purchases. So, there's no problem. It's the same for Mac OS X and iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did transfer both iOS and Mac applications from one account to another. It was fairly easy, and I did everything from itunesconnect.apple.com. However, they did not contain any IAP products, but I think they should be automatically transferred as well. After all, what is the point to offer a free app, and someone else to earn money through In-App purchases, for instance. Everything is supposed to be available, the IAP purchases are supposed to be active as well.

Make sure:

1) Make sure the app and any In-App Purchase products it offers have a status that supports transfers.

2) Make sure that In-App Purchase product IDs on the app aren’t the same product IDs on any apps in the recipient’s account.

For more details, read here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: Thanks for your response - Good point. I agree, this probably falls into the category of "we would have heard about it if it didn't work". Just want to make certain there are no steps I need to take before proceeding.

Comment: Hi, I made an edit to the answer. Please up-vote and/or accept my answer if you consider it.

Comment: I have already read that document (and alluded to it in my question), but I'm sure that link will be helpful for people who have the same question in the future.